# How to import nodes with entity reference field through feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds, entities, importing-exporting

At the moment i have 2 content types.
The first (Target Communities) is a kind of category listing. These nodes already exist.

The second (Areas, many more nodes) shall be created from a csv import.

The Areas content type has a entity reference field set to the Target Community content type.

I assumed that i just attach the Target Community titles to the Area in the csv, but after import and node creation, the reference field is still empty.

Then i tried the import with the Target Community node id instead of the title, but this doesn't work eather, the entity refernce field in the created nodes remain empty.

So now, I'm quite clueless about what else to try or what other settings I may have missed.

The feed mapping is correct, all other fields work, including term references etc.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/feeds_entityreference

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22043/4134

At the moment there is a very active thread on d.o about adding this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this thread:
[How to map Feed Importer with my content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/feed-importer-mapping?rq=1)

Which points here:
http://www.zivtech.com/blog/feed-feeds-importing-referenced-rss-data#comment-1378

Very nice tutorial...very simple custom module required.