# How to map Feed Importer with my content type?

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

Here's my problem:

I'm using the "Feeds" module to import data from different RSS feeds. One of the feeds is:

```
http://www.happynews.com/rss/.aspx
```

As you can see, one of the elements is the "link" of each article.

How do I map that link with my content type? (note it's NOT the feed's link)

I've updated my content type "Feed item", adding a new text field to it called "Article link", attached it to the importer item and definitely can see the new field in the "target" options, however, it seems that in the "source" options there is no link field.

Is there a way to add "source" options to map them up with our targets?

Big thanks in advance for any help! I really appreciate it.

So far I found this article that might help to my problem above:

- http://www.zivtech.com/blog/feed-feeds-importing-referenced-rss-data#comment-1378

Answer (score 1):

> How do I map that link with my content type? (note it's NOT the feed's link)

You're right your feed link is NOT a feed link. The URL is simply incorrect and this issue has nothing to do with Feeds module.

`http://www.happynews.com/rss/.aspx` returns 404 but when you dig a little you can quickly find that `http://www.happynews.com/rss/` returns directories and other resources containing XML feeds.

For example https://www.happynews.com/rss/environment.aspx is a correct RSS channel titled "HappyNews - Environment" where you can see `<item>` XML nodes and each nested `<title><description><link><pubDate>` data.

To import such single channel you need:

- create importer with **HTTP Fetcher**
- and as a parser check **Common syndication parser** option
- in fetcher settings you should provide RSS source channel link, so in **Automatically add scheme** input simply paste link to the channel you want to import like `https://www.happynews.com/rss/environment.aspx`
- if right address is given Feeds **fetcher** will be able to"recognize" the scheme and all accessible fields should be visible on **mapping** tab in "Select a source" select field.

After all steps inluding RSS -> node fields mapping definitions you will be able to import data periodically (when [CRON](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron/overview) configured) or manually by running `http://you-site-address/import`

You can also attach importer to specific content type, this way source is imported by creating a node of that content type.
  .